# How come the counting theorem isn't working here

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was doing a seemingly trivial question, and I though it was a simple application of the counting theorem but it turns out it doesn't work. Here's the question

> From a deck of 52 cards, how many ways are there to arrange a hand of
>   5 cards such that all 4 kings are in the hand (order doesn't matter) (the last card can be any non-king)

Now here's my thought process as an application of the counting principle:
$$ \frac{4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 48}{5!}$$

As we have $4!$ ways of placing the kings and then the last card can be from 48 other cards. Then we divide by $5!$ to remove the order. Unfortunately, this produces a non-integer so I was very sad indeed. However, it logically seems like it should work as it follows what I think is valid logic. Could someone explain how to get the correct answer (48) and also more importantly, why my logic was incorrect?

Comment: Not following.  The only question is...what's the non-king?  As there are $48$ non-kings, the answer is $48$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you add order to the hand but only partially.  That is, you order the kings but you don't tell us which four cards are kings.  But then you divide by $5!$ as if you had ordered everything in the hand.  If, for whatever reason, you wish to add order properly and then remove it, the formula would be $\frac {5!\times 48}{5!}=48$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, the last card is any non-king - sorry for confusion. i understand intuitively why the answer is 48 but I dont see why my logic was flawed

Comment: Well, can you follow my last comment?  In brief, your logic is flawed because you are partially restoring order to the hand, but not completely, so that when you remove the order you go too far.

Comment: I'm not happy with the question: arrange is a word that I take to mean order. Very different from how many ways to choose such a hand: there are 48 ways to choose the hand, and 4! ways to order it with the last card non king, making 48 * 4! ways to have the hand in that order, but you can't then divide by 5! to remove the chosen ordering, if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

When you write $$4\times 3\times 2\times 1\times 48$$
you haven't chosen yet exactly *where* the non-king is in the sequence.

Yet when you divide by $5!$ you pretend that you have done so. That's where your argument fails.